# What is the fastest possible way to read a serial port in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, serial-port

I need a serial port program to read data coming in at `4800` baud. Right now I have a simulator sending 15 lines of data every second. The output of it seems to get "behind" and can't keep up with the speed/amount of data coming in.

I have tried using `ReadLine()` with a `DataReceieved` event, which did not seem to be reliable, and now I am using an async method with `serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync`:

```
okToReadPort = true;
Task readTask = new Task(startAsyncRead);
readTask.Start();

//this method starts the async read process and the "nmeaList" is what 
// is used by the other thread to display data
  public async void startAsyncRead()
        {
            while (okToReadPort)
            {               
                Task<string> task = ReadLineAsync(serialPort);                
                string line = await task;
                NMEAMsg tempMsg = new NMEAMsg(line);
                if (tempMsg.sentenceType != null)
                {
                    nmeaList[tempMsg.sentenceType] = tempMsg;
                }
            }

        public static async Task<string> ReadLineAsync(
            this SerialPort serialPort)

        {
           // Console.WriteLine("Entering ReadLineAsync()...");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1];
            string ret = string.Empty;
            while (true)
            {
                await serialPort.BaseStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, 1);
                 ret += serialPort.Encoding.GetString(buffer);

                if (ret.EndsWith(serialPort.NewLine))
                    return ret.Substring(0, ret.Length - serialPort.NewLine.Length);
            }
        }
```

This still seems inefficient, does anyone know of a better way to  ensure that every piece of data is read from the port and accounted for?

Comment: Have you tried `ReadExisting` and parse the incoming data afterwards? If you read every second you should have plenty of time

Comment: Reading the Serial port one byte at a time seems very odd. Heres a quick web example of a method to reliably (according to author) read a serial port. http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Found it by googling.

Comment: @PhillipH: My blog post doesn't describe how to set buffer size, because it is so specific to the device and protocol.  Generally I set an inter-character timeout, but .NET doesn't make that easy.  And jerry did already take my advice by switching to `port.BaseStream.ReadAsync`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, your issue is that you are performing IO synchronously with data processing. It doesn't help that your data processing is relatively expensive (string concatenation).

To fix the general problem, when you read a byte put it into a processing buffer (`BlockingCollection` works *great* here as it solves Producer/Consumer) and have another thread read from the buffer. That way the serial port can immediately begin reading again instead of waiting for your processing to finish.

As a side note, you would likely see a benefit by using `StringBuilder` in your code instead of string concatenation. You should still process via queue though.

Comment: thanks for the tip! it seems to be working much better with the BlockingCollection. More improvements to come once I touch up the Strings

Comment: can i see the BlockingCollection implementation you have used?

Comment: @Mark unfortunately I don't have access to the code anymore

Comment: @BradleyDotNET i was able to fix my issue without using it, i found out that the event DataReceived didn't fire as much as i thought, so i had the buffer full of data, since i wanted to process 16 bytes at the time. now using a recursive function i go through the buffer, using the same event :)